# IBOutlet is nil inside viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I had a swift app rejected by App Review because it crashed on launch.

I symbolicated the crash report and found this:

```
...
OS Version:          iOS 9.0.2 (13A452)
...
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000048
Triggered by Thread:  0
...
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   myappname                   0x00000001000d88e8 specialized NetworkDiagramViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (NetworkDiagramViewController.swift:117)
1   myappname                   0x00000001000d77a4 @objc NetworkDiagramViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (NetworkDiagramViewController.swift:0)
2   UIKit                           0x000000018b7af610 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1124
...
```

Here are the relevant sections of NetworkDiagramViewController.swift:

```
...
11: class NetworkDiagramViewController: UIViewController {
12: 
13:    @IBOutlet weak var serverLabel: UILabel!
...
29:    override func viewDidLoad() {
30:        super.viewDidLoad()
31:        updateCloudViews()
32:    }
...
116:   private func updateCloudViews() {
117:       serverLabel.text = ServerSettings.host ?? " "
118:   }
...
```

I've double checked that the serverLabel outlet is correctly hooked up in the storyboard. This crash never happens on any of my test devices or in the simulator.

Comment: Are any other outlets nil?  How are you initializing that view controller?  If initializing programmatically, it may not be loading the view from Interface Builder.  Consider instantiating from the Storyboard file (if you're not doing so already).

Comment: you can also do your updateCloudViews code in the label property observer didSet method

Comment: SIGSEGV is not a nil exception...

Comment: JAL, other outlets are properly initialized. This view controller is created from a storyboard (contained in a navigation controller presented by a ShowDetail segue in a split view controller).

Comment: Lukas, that would probably be a better place to do this. However, I'm still concerned that the storyboard is failing to initialize some outlets before viewDidLoad. I thought that was part of viewDidLoad's contract.